# Why is it recommended to add sqlite database to gitignore?

Tags: django, sqlite

I understand other files being ignored. But why would I want to ignore the SQLite database file if that holds data needed to run the website? How can the website function without a database?

Comment: the database may have some sensitive data

Comment: @JPG How can the website function without a database?

Comment: @micahkam: if there is no `.sqlite`, it will be constructed by default. So if you deploy it and run migration, the server will construct a new database at the server sid.e

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So will the data be re-created somehow?

Comment: Assume that you have a project in Github and it is ***public***. SO, anyone can clone your project and inspect your ***sqlite database***. It is not a problem unless you have some sensitive data in it. (Assume that you have 100k customer details in that ***DB file*** and now it's public). Usually, people don't use sqlite for production purposes (at least 99% don't) because it lack many things

Answer (score 2):

You probably only want to write to one instance of the file.  This means it either lives in production or in your sandbox.  If you change data in production, it's now newer than what you are tracking in git, and it will presumable be overwritten on the next deploy causing data loss.

Couple of minor issues:

1. git doesn't perform well when you store large binary files in it.
2. git can track binary files (like images) but you don't get as much value like being able to diff your .sqlite file before/after a change.

Comment: So assuming i was using a better database service, id assume since the connection would be based on port protocols the development and production would interact with the same database that way?

Comment: The gist of my answer is that you want a single place to write the data.  If your database lives elsewhere it's certainly fine to write to that database from multiple places.  That said, best practice it to strictly separate development and production.  You don't want a "mistake" in development causing production issues.  Or a more positive spin, you want the freedom to explore changes in dev, say, delete all the data, or maybe reproduce a problem with fake data.

Answer (score 0):

Because you should want to use different databases on testing environment and production environment